# Explain me my LISP code

Tags: lisp

I'm new in LISP and I'm trying to understand recursion.

What I know is that recursion needs a STOP condition. In my code below, can you explain to me why `(equal x 0) 1` is my STOP condition SINCE `fact(- X 1)` could continue indefinitely as in my second condition, I have set to `t` the second line of my `cond` which means it should continue.

BUT when I run the program, it works fine though. Below is my code (found by chance)

```
(defun fact(x)
    (cond
        ((equal x 0) 1)
        (t (*(fact(- x 1)) x)) 
    )
)
```

Comment: I could continue indefinitely if you passed a negative number.

Comment: The result of either consequent or alternative is the value of the if and the last expression is the return value. In JS it would be like: `function fact(x) { return x === 0 ? 1 : x * fact(x-1);}`

Answer (score 0):

`cond` expresssions have a number of clauses. Each clause is of the form `(expr1 expr2)`. If the `expr1` evaluates to true then `expr2 is evaluated and that is the returned value of the`cond`. No other clauses are evaluated.

So, once `x` becomes `0` the first clauses of `cond` evaluates to true and that call to `fact` returns `1`.

The other clause of `cond` has a first expression of `t` which is true by definition; thus if the first clause is not used it always uses the second clause. (A `cond` clause with `t` is like an "else" in an "if" statement in other langugaes.)

This function is recursive, if you call it with an argument of 2, it checks if 2 == 0, it doesn't so then it multiplies 2 with the value returned by recursively calling itself with 1. Since 1 != 0 it will return the value of 1 multiplied by the value of recursively calling itself with 0. Since 0 does equal 0 it just returns 1, which is used one layer to return 1 which is then used at the top layer of this recursion to return 2.

Common Lisp has a function [`trace`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm) which will let you see when your function is called and with what arguments. Typically each recursive call will be indented so you can see something like this:

```
(fact 2)
    (fact 1)
       (fact 0)
```

Which can be helpful for understanding this function.

(As mentioned in a comment - this function doesn't catch the case of a negative input - but that is error handling and could be easily fixed).